# Does ただな mean the same thing as ただの?

Tags: word-choice

According to http://www.jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0&eng=&dict=edict, ただ is a na-adjective.

People seem to use ただの exelucisvely, and I wonder what ただな means.

What does ただな mean?

Comment: Which ただ are you referring to? There is more than one word referenced there, and not all are listed as na-adjectives.

Comment: Let me change the question.

Which class of word does 'ただ' belong to in 'ただの'?
What does "ただの" mean?

Since jisho lists it as a na-adjective, I was wondering if ただの means the same thing as ただな

Comment: Actually, if you look at the page closely, it says that it's a ***no**-adjective*, though I don't know what kind of thing it is :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「ただ**な**」 is NOT an adjective in the same way that 「きれいな」,「みごとな」, etc. are.  Thus, a noun ***cannot*** follow 「ただな」.

「ただ**な**」 is usually used like an ***interjection*** at the beginning of a sentence that is said in reply to a statement made by another person.  It means something along the lines of:

> "One thing that we have to consider is ~~", "One thing you shouldn't forget is ~~", "We can't go without mentioning ~~", etc.
>
> A feminine version is 「ただ**ね**」.  「ただ**な**」 sounds pretty masculine.

***Other "ただ + particle" forms and their usages:***

「ただ**で**」 = "for free"

「ただ**の**」 = "ordinary", "run-of-the-mill", etc.  It can also mean "free (of charge)".

Answer (score 5):

As @nkjt said, notice that the modern *tada* = "ordinary, free, as-is" **isn't** listed as a na-adjective.

Perhaps you're thinking of the [直]{ただ} entry.  Contrary to what the jisho.org site says, this isn't a na-adjective.  Rather, it's a **nari**-adjective – the Classical Japanese ancestor to na-adjectives (notice jisho.org marks it as "archaic").  *Tada-nari* is a Classical adjective meaning "direct, straight, only, normal".

Sources:

- The Ōbunsha Classical Japanese dictionary has *tada-nari*;
- The *Digital Daijirin* entry for *tada* [lists it](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/136674/m0u/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0/) as both a noun and a nari-adjective;
- *Meikyō Kokugo Jiten* doesn't list modern *tada* as na-adjective, just as noun, adverb, or prefix.

Comment: 広辞苑 doesn't list anything as a 形容動詞, by the way.

Comment: @snailboat That's correct.  I expect Kōjien is deliberately staying away from the Classical variation (well, at least the abridged version I have at hand).

Comment: I mean no words in the entire dictionary are listed that way; they don't acknowledge it as a part of speech, and lump them all in with nouns.  (I have the full version and I'm not sure what the abridged version is like.)

Comment: Ah, I see, I get you now.  Thanks for the clarification!  I'll remove it from the answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably adverb ただ and interjecting particle な, which conveys a flavor like "ok?"/ "sure?".